# e Function Parity

Tags: functions

I have look at the plot of the function $$(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$$
Is it an odd or even function? it seems like one flip on the Y-axis and on flip on the X-axis but unlike odd it is a flip upward 

Aren't all functions (or just continuous?)  $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are a direct sum of odd and even functions?

[image]

Comment: Odd or even function can be simply checked by computing $f(-x)$. As is evident, from the graph, it is neither.

Comment: Moreover, since $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} = e$, if it were a translate of an odd function, it would be $\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x - e$, but evaluating at, e.g., $x = \pm 1$ shows that this function is not odd.

Comment: How is your function defined for $-1 < x <0$, where both base and exponent are negative?

Comment: @Arpan Can a function have no parity?

Comment: @MartinR it is undefined over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @gbox What do you mean by parity?

Comment: @Arpan odd or even, Isn't there a theorem about the direct sum of both?

Comment: @gbox I am not familiar with such a theorem, could you reference it and add it to your question so others could answer it better?

Comment: @Arpan did not find the theorem, but added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is neither odd nor even:

- A function is even if, for every $x$, $f(-x)=f(x)$.
- A function is odd if, for every $x$, $f(x) = -f(x)$.

Neither condition is satisfied in your case, since $f(-1) = \frac12$ and $f(1)=2$, and $\frac 12 \neq 2, -2$.

What's more, a function that has a non-symmetric domain can never be odd or even. In your case, $f(-\frac12)$ is not defined, but $f(\frac 12)$ is, and comparing these two values (which must be done for a function to be odd or even) is impossible.